# modifying URL structure in django/tastypie API

Tags: python, django, url, tastypie

I've got a tastypie API made with following code:

```
v1_api = Api(api_name='v1')
v1_api.register(UserResource())
v1_api.register(IncomeCategoryResource())
v1_api.register(OutcomeCategoryResource())
v1_api.register(IncomeResource())
v1_api.register(OutcomeResource())

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^api/', include((v1_api.urls))), # model urls
)
```

I've set `json` to be the default formatting, so I don't have to provide the `?format=json` each time I access API. My URLs look like this so far:

`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/`

`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/incomecategory/`

etc. I would like them to look like this:

`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user.json`

`http://localhost:8000/api/v1/incomecategory.json`

How can I do that with tastypie? I've tried some experiments with `def prepend_urls(self):` inside `ModelResource` classes but it didn't work at all. I guess this could be configurable somewhere inside `Api` (`from tastypie.api import Api`). Than you for any hints...

Comment: this is just an idea i got by looking at tastypie code.. i think you can use this https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/utils/urls.py#L5 and make it look like .json as it is being used here https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/api.py#L102

Answer (score 0):

add

```
incomecategory.json
```

to your resource_name

and add this to your ModelResource

```
 def determine_format(self, request):
        return 'application/json'
```

and in settings.py add this line

```
TASTYPIE_ALLOW_MISSING_SLASH = True
```